# User's first ever post wrongly (in my opinion) auto-deleted for being spam/abusive

Tags: discussion, spam, automatic-deletion

The revision history shows the original post before it was auto-deleted. No abuse is apparent and the only "spam" is a link to a book on Amazon. Why was this deleted?

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75420044/revisions

Comment: Might not have been the only post by that user that advertised this book. But only a moderator can tell for sure.

Comment: That last sentence reads *a lot* like spam to me.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: The user is still active and is (afaik) not suspended. I added a screenshot such that <10k users can also see what is discussed.

Comment: That last sentence reads like spam. If it quacks like spam, and looks like spam, it’s probably spam. Let’s not get into the fact, the code, if I went looking for that snippet would I find it elsewhere?

Comment: Not enough to make me change my opinion I'm afraid...

Comment: The shortened link resolves to `https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Data-Science-Python-hands/dp/1801071977?keywords=python+for+data+science&amp;qid=1676114799&amp;sr=8-3-spons&amp;psc=1&amp;spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyMEZZUkxKRzhSM1BCJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMTgyNDE3UjdYSlgyTzlHMVo5JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAzOTA1MTIxVTZYSlhQTkJISUZHJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ%3D%3D&amp;linkCode=sl1&amp;tag=abdwalid04-20&amp;linkId=301a211e6084788c714fe333df8f6e9c&amp;language=en_US&amp;ref_=as_li_ss_tl`.

Comment: ... I'm not familiar enough with Amazon to tell whether this is an affiliate link which earns the poster a commission, but it looks vaguely like it.

Comment: Hmm quite possibly

Comment: Going by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919290 and the `tag=abdwalid04-20` part of the URL, yes, that's an affiliate link for the answerer. (And the main body of the answer looks like it might well be ChatGPT-generated as well...)

Comment: FWIW even *if* the post didn't have the spam link the rest of the content has a 99.98% chance of being generated by ChatGPT, so we don't want that content anyway.

Comment: The user has [another deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419821) which also has an Amazon affiliated link in it. Moreover it includes the phrase "You'll notice that the del method is much faster than the pop method, as expected based on the explanation in my previous answer." when the user *doesn't* have another previous answer. That is usually a sign the content was copied. Spammers often copy plausible sounding content then add their spam link. (and yeah - nowadays ChatGPT is also used for this same thing)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The post was deleted by the community user, most likely in response to multiple spam flags from users; some of these might have been generated by Smokey, while others by users who read the post. As a result the post was deleted and marked as spam, stopping any further interactions. The key part of why it would have been detected is the closing sentence, which is a link to a product on Amazon.

In addition to the spam like portion of the post, even if we ignore that we still don't want the post; it has a *very* high probability of being generated by ChatGPT based on certain indicators and a detector agrees with this denoting the opening paragraph has a **99.98%** chance of being generated by OpenAI.

As I typed this answer as well, [VLAZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423365/users-first-ever-post-wrongly-in-my-opinion-auto-deleted-for-being-spam-abusi#comment948176_423365) they found [another deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419821) which also contains an Amazon link. This suggests that the malicious intent (that it was meant as an advertisement, rather than a user who "didn't know" ChatGPT content is **banned**) is more likely.

Comment: this is a correct assessment of the situation

Comment: I got this answer as a poor quality answer review test, which I obviously failed..... now I understand why, thank you!

Comment: @tomredfern There has been some discussion about whether or not spam-deleted (and, more recently, AI-generated) answers should be used as audits in LQA. As it stands, the only way mods can prevent them from being selected is to undelete them and then re-delete them as "Rude or Abusive" (such posts aren't used as audits). But that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Yes, there were a series of posts from this user (and another one) spamming Amazon links to a particular book. I nuked them all myself. I intentionally did not use a rude/abusive flag to nuke these because I thought they were valid audits. I admit that the *first* one I saw caught me out, too (I made an edit before realizing it was spam). But I realized it was spam looking only at that single post, then went looking for more. There's ample evidence in the post itself for a reviewer to determine that it's spam or *in some way* unacceptable content for SO, which is all you need to pass an audit.